# pyserial read qr code and take action on arduino

Tags: python, opencv, arduino, qr-code, pyserial

I'm reading qr code using opencv and pyzbar, i'm communicating with an arduino uno using pyserial.

my python code

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode 
import cv2
import serial
import time

arduino = serial.Serial(port='COM6', baudrate=115200, timeout=1)

def write_read(x):
  arduino.write(bytes(x, 'utf-8'))
  time.sleep(0.05)
  data = arduino.readline()
  return data

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


def get_qr_data(input_frame):
  try:
      return decode(input_frame)
  except:
      return []

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    qr_obj = get_qr_data(frame)
    cv2.imshow("DD", frame)
    print(qr_obj)
    # cv2.imshow("DD2", frame2)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):


        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

from `qr_obj = get_qr_data(frame)` i get the result `[Decoded(data='asd', type='QRCODE', rect=Rect(left=115, top=155, width=225, height=223), polygon=[Point(x=115, y=378), Point(x=340, y=370), Point(x=335, y=155), Point(x=119, y=155)], quality=1, orientation='UP')]`

im trying to print the qr data in arduino serial monitor and turn on the arduino built in led

my arduino code

```
char x;
void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
Serial.setTimeout(1);
pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
while (!Serial.available());
x = Serial.read();
Serial.println(x);

    if(Serial.read() == x)
   {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
     }
 }
```

The built in led doesn't turn on and nothing is written in the serial monitor

Comment: I'm not sure what you expected `if(Serial.read() == x)` to do, but that's not what you want.  And I don't see you calling `write_read` anywhere.

Comment: Your Arduino code needs to be in an infinite loop doing `x = Serial.read();` calls, which returns one byte at a time.  You will need some kind of a signal to tell the Arduino when you are done.  Perhaps you could send a newline.  Also remember the serial FIFOs are only 64 bytes long.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to copy everything you get.  You will need some way to know when the transmission is complete.  So, in your Python:

```
def write_read(x):
  arduino.write(bytes(x, 'utf-8'))
  arduino.write(b'\n')
  time.sleep(0.05)
  data = arduino.readline()
  return data
```

Then, in Arduino land, something like this:

```
void loop() {
  while (!Serial.available());
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  while( (x = Serial.Read()) != '\n' )
  {
    Serial.print(x);
  }
  Serial.print('\n');
}
```